# Collecting value of int array using normal JAVA Stream

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

In my program,  I am trying to print sorted int array using stream. But I am getting false output while using normal stream. And correct details are getting printed while using int stream.

Please refer below core snippet for more details.

```
package com.test.sort.bubblesort;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BubbleSortWithRecursion {

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr, int n) {

        if (n < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int prevValue;
        int nextValue;
        for (int index = 0; index < n-1; index++) {
            prevValue = arr[index];
            nextValue = arr[index+1];

            if  (prevValue > nextValue) {
                arr[index] = nextValue;
                arr[index+1] = prevValue;
            }
        }

        bubbleSort(arr, n-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[] = new int[] {10,1,56,8,78,0,12};
        bubbleSort(arr, arr.length);

        **//False Output** :  [I@776ec8df
        String output = Arrays.asList(arr)
            .stream()
            .map(x -> String.valueOf(x))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        System.out.println(output);

        //Correct Output : 0,1,8,10,12,56,78
        String output2 = IntStream
            .of(arr)
            .boxed()
            .map(x -> Integer.toString(x))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(","));

        System.out.println(output2);

    }


}
```

And I am getting following output on console :

```
[I@776ec8df
0,1,8,10,12,56,78
```

The fist line of output was generated using normal java stream which is not correct.

Why am I getting false content using normal JAVA stream ? Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(arr)` returns a `List<int[]>` whose only element is `arr`. Therefore streaming that `List` and then mapping that single element to `String.valueOf(x)` and collecting with `Collectors.joining(",")` will result in a `String` whose value is that single array's `toString()`, which is the output you see.

```
String output = Arrays.asList(arr) // List<int[]>
    .stream() // Stream<int[]>
    .map(x -> String.valueOf(x)) // Stream<String> having a single element - "[I@776ec8df"
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // "[I@776ec8df"
```

When you create an `IntStream` from the `int` array, you get a stream of the individual elements (the `int` values), so you can box them, convert then to `String`s and join them to get the desired output.

You can make your first snippet work if you change:

```
int arr[] = new int[] {10,1,56,8,78,0,12};
```

to:

```
Integer arr[] = new Integer[] {10,1,56,8,78,0,12};
```

since this way `Arrays.asList(arr)` will produce a `List<Integer>` containing all the elements of the input array.

Comment: Thank you for sharing answer. Still I have one confusion. Arrays.asList generate List<int[]> while using primitive  type. Should not it produce List<Integer[]> while using wrapper type ?

Comment: @GunjanShah to understand it better, Integer is an Object, int is just a native type, so when you use array of native type it can considered as one Object, instead of array of Integer it considered as array of Objects

Comment: @GunjanShah The signature is `static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`. T must be a reference type, so if you pass a primitive array, the array itself is that reference type. If you pass an array of some reference type (such as Integer array), T becomes the element type of the array (Integer).

Comment: wow... this was looking simple but very good concept is hidden here. This answer helped me to make my varargs concept more clear. Thank You !

Answer (score 10):

You can solve your issue like so :

```
String output = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .boxed()
        .map(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(",")); // 0,1,8,10,12,56,78
```

Explain what happen :

when you use `Arrays.asList()` which look :

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

it took varargs of type `T`, in your case you use it for `int[]` Object, so `Arrays.asList()` will return `List` of `int[]` and not a stream of ints, so instead you have to use `Arrays.stream` which look like this :

```
public static IntStream stream(int[] array) {
    return stream(array, 0, array.length);
}
```

to get the correct data.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the suggestion here. Your answer is smilar to Eran's answer but Varargs mapping  explanation is more clearly explained in Eran's answer. So accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even a bit shorter:

```
String output = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

The result is `0,1,8,10,12,56,78`

First you create an `IntStream`, then you get a `Stream<String>` which is collected to the final `String`.